# Marco function error expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '{' token

Tags: c, macros

I have tried to write this function using Macros

```
unsigned int put_0_right(unsigned int value, int order)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<order; i++)
            value=clear_bit(value,i);
        return value;
    }
```

so I wrote this

```
#define unsigned int mettre_0_droite(value, order)(\
                            {\
                            int i=0;\
                            for(i=0; i<order; i++)\
                                {value=clear_bit(value,i);}\
                            return value;\
                            })
```

but I am getting this error **expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '{' token**

Comment: Function-like macros don't have return types.  Lose the `unsigned int` before `mettre_0_droite`.

Comment: Also function-like macros don't have `return` statements.

Comment: Also function-like macros are generally considered a bad idea these days.  Is there a reason you're trying to write `mettre_0_droite` as a macro?  It's going to be very difficult to get it to "return" the computed `value`.

Comment: how can I make it return "value" ?

Comment: You are right
but it's required in my task to write some functions in macros

Comment: I don't know of a way to have it return `value` in this case.  There's probably a gcc extension that would let you do it, but I suspect it's impossible in portable code.  I recommend using an ordinary function, or an inline function.  As I said, these are vastly preferred over function-like macros in modern code.

Comment: Your task is teaching you a very bad lesson, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd suggest you read more about macros - they are _not_ part of the compiled code in C language. They are substituted and expanded in the source file _before_ the file gets compiled. What results from macros' substitution _may_ result in a function declaration, as C languade defines it, but the macro itself is _not_ a function.

Comment: I think that too. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the task is probably to do something like this.

```
#define mettre_0_droite(value, order) ((value) & (~((1ul << ((order) + 1)) - 1)))
```

instead of loops

And if you do not understand the difference between the function and the macro you need a good C book.